How does timer-interrupt occur in XV6?
I implemented thread's switching using functions like thread_schedule(), and thread_yield(), which aim at saving current thread's registers and state and loading next thread's one.
I now want to implement the same thing using timer-interrupt in xv6, but I don't know how it works.

Timer interrupts are handled by the trap function in trap.c. The ticks counter is updated there, and also yield() is called.
Since there is no multi-threading in xv6 I assume your are just implementing it. In this case, notice that in a way, threading is implemented, it is just that each thread has its own address space and set of resources. So really what you are implementing is a means to share resources between threads rather than really implementing the concept of threads and context switches.

So what u mean is that the threads are sharing the resources except of each thread's stack and registers, isn't it? Then where does interrupt are actually called in? Does it depend on the UPROGS that you trynna run?

What I mean is that you can keep the original struct proc and think about it as a thread and make it share resources with other struct procs and then you don't need to change anything in the context switch code. Something like adding a new struct shared_proc that multiple procs have a pointer to.

Still don't get it 100%, but I think it's on me. Thanks a lot for your efforts:D

Think about this way: currently you have some struct procs that are context-switched between them. Each has its own stack and set of registers. This is the same as a system with processes with each process having one thread. To implement multithreading you just need to make these struct procs which are already behaving like threads, share resources like memory space and open files.

You can do this by adding a pointer from each 'thread' (actually a struct proc) to its process (the shared parts of the struct proc). Then in every operation that requires a thread, you use the struct proc, and if you need to change the shared parts (like in growproc) you use the proc->shared struct. If you don't feel comfortable with the thread struct being called proc you can change the name. But the main thing is that struct proc behaves already like a thread in many ways so you can use it like this.

Thanks a lot. It helped me a lot:D
